# Scrolling with a middle mouse button stops with a lag

Tags: windows-xp, firefox

If I scroll a page by dragging middle mouse button and then want to stop scrolling by putting mouse pointer back, it happens with a delay and I scroll past the point I want to stop near.

Firefox 19, Windows XP. Other browsers, firefox 3 included, seem to not have this issue, although FF3 scrolled slower.

Comment: Did you make sure hardware acceleration is on (or forced on). This improves performance.

Comment: All four checkboxes in settings are on.